# How do I highlight rows based on latest time stamp in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 4 columns, A B C D.

- Column A has a designed value.
- Column B has a reviewed value.
- Column C is empty.
- Column D has a formula which returns false if value in column A does not match value in column B.  Also, Column D is always hidden.

I need help in highlighting the row or giving some color to column C if D has false in it.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/799063-conditional-formatting-highlight-a-row-based-on-one-cell-value.html has this question. Highlight column c and replace A with D in your case. Note this only works in Excel 2010.

> So if I understand you correctly, you want to highlight A1:J1 if A1 is "HIGH PRIORITY". And you want to highlight A3:J3 if A3 is "HIGH PRIORITY", etc.?
>
> If so, select your full range, e.g. A1:J100, then set the conditional formatting rule to:
>
> =$A1="HIGH PRIORITY"
>
> The row number will properly adjust for the condition of each row, but the column will stay the same (A).

Answer (score 0):

Select Column C, then click on Conditional Formatting -> New Rule and choose to "Use a formula": `=$D1=FALSE`. Pick how you want to format the cells like with fill color. This will highlight all the cells in Column C on the rows where Column D is `FALSE`. If you want to highlight the entire row, then highlight all the relevant columns (like A:C), then use the same formula.

If you want it to highlight cells if `FALSE` is in Column C *or* D, then use the formula: `=AND($C1,$D1)=FALSE` (this works if Column C is empty, or if Column C has true/false values in it).